# Using Elements of One Dataframe Column to Select Values in Another Dataframe to Create a Third Dataframe Using Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
```

The code provided below creates three dataframes - Main, LookUp and Final. I'm trying to use the Main and LookUp dataframes to create the Final dataframe.

For example, the Final table only keeps the "Sections" that have the number provided in Section_Lookup of the LookUp table, while also keeping the corresponding "Title" variable.

I would like to use tidyverse as much as possible. Most of my attempts have been along the lines of the code below. I'm thinking that using two loops, or purrr, will allow me to loop over the Main and LookUp tables. This is more advanced than what I usually attempt, so I would like some help on how to proceed and work with this type of situation.

```
New<-map(Main, function(x) {
map(LookUp, function(y) if_else(x$Title1==y$Title_Lookup & ...x$Section1 CONTAINS Y SECTION_LOOKUP... ) )}),
```

Sample code is below:

Main Dataframe:

```
    Title1<-c("101A", "101A", "101A", "101A", "101A", "101A", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "400B", "400B", "400B", "400B", "200A", "200A", "250D", "250D", "250D", "250D")
Section1<-c("2A", "2A", "2B", "2B", "2B", "2C", "2A", "2A", "4A", "4A", "4A", "4B", "4B", "4C", "4C", "4C", "4C", "4D", "4D", "2A", "2A", "2B", "2B", "2A", "6A", "1A", "1B", "2A", "2A")
Main<-data_frame(Title1,Section1)
```

LookUp Table:

```
Title_Lookup<-c("101A", "203S", "203S", "400B", "200A", "200A", "250D")
Section_Lookup<-c(2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 6, 2)
LookUp<-data_frame(Title_Lookup,Section_Lookup)
```

Final Dataframe:

```
Section_Final<-c("2A", "2B", "2C", "2A", "4A", "4B", "4C", "4D", "2A", "2B", "2A", "6A", "2A")
Title_Final<-c("101A", "101A", "101A", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "400B", "400B", "200A", "200A", "250D")
Final<-data_frame(Title_Final,Section_Final)
```

Comment: This sounds like a join with a little cleanup of key columns first, but the result seems to pick and choose parts of each with a logic that escapes me

Comment: How does the output data have 3 rows with Name1 / 101A when the main data frame only has 1 row with Name1 / 101A?

Comment: I simplified the example so now there's only the "Title" and "Section" columns. I apologize for over-complicating. Hopefully you can take another look and still help me out...

Comment: I was developing an answer based on your previous examples. Now my answer looked "wrong" because you changed your example datasets. I will update my answer later, but please avoid this kind of situation in the future.

Comment: To elaborate on the logic, using Title "101A" as an example, the LookUp table's Section_Lookup shows "2' for "101A", so this means that only Section1 variables from the "Main" table that contain 2 should be used in the Final dataframe - which include 2A, 2B, and 2C. Each only needs to be shown once, with the corresponding Title (101A) repeating for each.

Comment: MKR, dplyr is fine! Dplyr is part of the tidyverse - so dplyr, tidyr, purrr, etc, are all what I want...so please go ahead with dplyr.

Comment: www, I apologize for making changes that affected your answer. I appreciate your help and like the approach you're taking, but is it possible to replace the data.table function with a tidyverse approach? The people who will be using the code prefer tidyverse and are not familiar with data.table...

Comment: @Mike I have updated my answer. Since you changed your example datasets, the `data.table` package is no longer required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse). The `str_replace` function is from [stringr](/questions/tagged/stringr), which is part of the [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse). If you just want to load the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package, you can use `sub("\\D+$", "", Section1)` instead of `str_replace`.

```
library(tidyverse)
Main2 <- Main %>%
  mutate(Number = as.numeric(str_replace(Section1, "\\D+$", ""))) %>%
  semi_join(LookUp, by = c("Title1" = "Title_Lookup",
                           "Number" = "Section_Lookup")) %>%
  select(Title_Final = Title1,  Section_Final = Section1) %>%
  distinct() 
Main2
# # A tibble: 13 x 2
#    Title_Final Section_Final
#    <chr>       <chr>        
#  1 101A        2A           
#  2 101A        2B           
#  3 101A        2C           
#  4 203S        2A           
#  5 203S        4A           
#  6 203S        4B           
#  7 203S        4C           
#  8 203S        4D           
#  9 400B        2A           
# 10 400B        2B           
# 11 200A        2A           
# 12 200A        6A           
# 13 250D        2A
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this is a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on the `sqldf` package, taking advantage of `charindex()` to see whether the string in Section_Lookup is present in Section1.

```
library(tidyverse)
Title1<-c("101A", "101A", "101A", "101A", "101A", "101A", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "400B", "400B", "400B", "400B", "200A", "200A", "250D", "250D", "250D", "250D")
Section1<-c("2A", "2A", "2B", "2B", "2B", "2C", "2A", "2A", "4A", "4A", "4A", "4B", "4B", "4C", "4C", "4C", "4C", "4D", "4D", "2A", "2A", "2B", "2B", "2A", "6A", "1A", "1B", "2A", "2A")
Main<-data_frame(Title1,Section1)

Title_Lookup<-c("101A", "203S", "203S", "400B", "200A", "200A", "250D")
Section_Lookup<-as.character(c(2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 6, 2))
LookUp<-data_frame(Title_Lookup,Section_Lookup)

sqlQuery <- "select distinct a.Title1 as Title, a.Section1 as Section 
                    from Main as a
             left join LookUp as b 
             where 
             a.Title1 = b.Title_Lookup and
             charindex(b.Section_Lookup,a.Section1) > 0"
sqldf(sqlQuery)
```

...and the output.

```
> sqldf(sqlQuery)
   Title Section
1   101A      2A
2   101A      2B
3   101A      2C
4   203S      2A
5   203S      4A
6   203S      4B
7   203S      4C
8   203S      4D
9   400B      2A
10  400B      2B
11  200A      2A
12  200A      6A
13  250D      2A
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be based on joining only on `Section` column.

```
library(dplyr)
Name1<-c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", "Name7", "Name8", "Name9",
         "Name10", "Name11", "Name12", "Name13", "Name14", "Name15", "Name16", "Name17",
         "Name18", "Name19", "Name20", "Name21", "Name22", "Name23", "Name24", "Name25",
         "Name26", "Name27", "Name28", "Name29")
Code<-c(10123, 13432, 34554, 45563, 43666, 54444, 55322, 52111, 33443, 88998, 54554,
        33455, 65889, 88888, 22344, 54455, 66655, 22222, 65564, 77677, 65545, 67765,
        34334, 88789, 76776, 67765, 55555, 65445, 65665)
Title1<-c("101A", "101A", "101A", "101A", "101A", "101A", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S",
          "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "203S", "400B",
          "400B", "400B", "400B", "200A", "200A", "250D", "250D", "250D", "250D")
Section1<-c("2A", "2A", "2B", "2B", "2B", "2C", "2A", "2A", "4A", "4A", "4A", "4B", "4B",
            "4C", "4C", "4C", "4C", "4D", "4D", "2A", "2A", "2B", "2B", "2A", "6A", "1A",
            "1B", "2A", "2A")
Main<-data_frame(Name1,Code,Title1,Section1)

Title_Lookup<-c("101A", "203S", "203S", "400B", "200A", "200A", "250D")
Section_Lookup<-c(2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 6, 2)
LookUp<-data_frame(Title_Lookup,Section_Lookup)

#create data.frame of distinct Sections
df_sections <- distinct(LookUp, Section_Lookup) %>% as.data.frame()

#Use filter to select those records having matching numeric value in Section
filter(Main, as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]).*","\\1",Section1)) %in% df$Section_Lookup) %>%
  select(Title1, Section1) %>% distinct()

#The result:
# A tibble: 13 x 2
   Title1 Section1
    <chr>    <chr>
 1   101A       2A
 2   101A       2B
 3   101A       2C
 4   203S       2A
 5   203S       4A
 6   203S       4B
 7   203S       4C
 8   203S       4D
 9   400B       2A
10   400B       2B
11   200A       2A
12   200A       6A
13   250D       2A
```